# get total for each pair of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Offer resource. an offer has many surfaces and services, and surfaces has many services.
In my view, I have a table displaying each associated records like:

```
  <%- @surfaces = @offer.surfaces %>
  <% @surfaces.each do |surface| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= surface.size %></td>
         <% surface.services.each do |service| %>
    <td>  <%= service.price %> </td>
         <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
```

And I want another td to display the total for each pair of surface.size service.price.
How can I implement this correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: you have many services associated to a surface, do you want the sum of the products of the service price and the surface size? and do this for all surfaces associated with an offer?

Comment: Yes, I want the total to consist of each surface size times each service price, because I want to render the total in a table td for each pair [size, price].

Comment: It's still not clear to me _what_ you want totaled. It'd be clearer if there was a concrete example.

Comment: I have edited my question, but, let's say I have a surface with size 2 and service with price 5. I want the total to return 10. Something like offer.services.last.price * offer.surfaces.last.size.

Comment: That's still not helpful. According to your description, 1 offer has many surfaces, 1 surface has 1 size and many services, 1 service has 1 price. What would the total for `offer = { :surfaces => [ { :size => 3, :services => [ { :price => 5 }, { :price => 7 } ] }, { :size => 11, :services => [ { :price => 13 }, { :price => 17 }, { :price => 19 } ] } ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like:

```
<%- @surfaces = @offer.surfaces %>
  <% @surfaces.each do |surface| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= surface.size %></td>
          <% surface.services.each do |service| %>
    <td>    <%= service.price %> </td>
    <td>    <%= service.price * surface.size %></td>

          <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Sorry for the unclear way of asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using 1 sql query

```
Surface
  .joins(:services)
  .where(offer_id: @offer.id)
  .sum('services.price * surfaces.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need something like:

```
def total
  tsize, tprice = 0, 0

  surfaces = @offer.surfaces
  tsize = surfaces.sum(&:size)
  surfaces.each { |s| tprice += s.services.sum(&:price) }

  (tsize * tprice)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean by 'total', but it sounds like you want the sum of products? The intentions behind your code aren't clear.

```
def total
  self.surfaces.map do |surface|
    surface.map do |service|
      surface.size * service.price
    end.sum
  end.sum
end
```